# Изменение значения в объекте JS

Tags: javascript

Допустим, что есть такой объект:

```
var pk = {
  One : '811-111'
}
```

Необходимо добавить к ключу One еще одно значение, как например, "111-395", чтобы получить вот такое:

```
var pk = {
  One : '811-111, 111-395'
}
```

Как осуществить данную операцию?

Comment: не лучше будет в массиве хранить?

Comment: Да, я уже к этому пришел, спасибо! `if (phonebook.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      phonebook[name].push(num)
    } else {
      phonebook[name] = [num];
    }` В итоге получается хранение массива номеров в значении.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самое простое решение.

```
 const pk = {
      One: '811-111'
 }

 pk.One = `${pk.One}, 111-395`
```

Если нужно будет сделать так со всеми полями объекта то можно использовать этот способ.

```
const addNumber = (obj, number) => {
     Object.keys(obj).forEach(el => obj[el] = `${obj[el]}, ${number}`)
}

addNumber(pk, '111-395')
```

Comment: зачем pk.One = `${pk.One}, 111-395` если можно pk.One += ', 111-395'

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько, потому что это читабельнее, чем это `pk.One += ', 111-395' `

Comment: ну да, зачем оператор += вообще сделали, проще же писать a = a + b чем a += b

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько потому что `+` для склеивания строк это априори выглядит не очень и шаблоны на порядок читабельнее. А операторы вроде `+, =, ++, +=` как то в нормальных языках используются только для чисел, да и созданы они для чисел, вам так не кажется? С таким мнением вам будет тяжело на собеседовании.

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов тоесть вы только что посмели назвали js ненормальным языком?

Comment: @Diskyp мне хватает опыта работы с этим языком чтобы говорить что он не идеальный.

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов какой язык по вашему идеальный? Какие работы, базирующиеся на JS, вы мне можете показать в поддержку ваших слов? Каковы аргументы к вашему утверждению? Из вашего комментария к моему ответу я и вовсе могу сделать вывод, что вы даже не знаете особенностей JSа.

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов, видя Ваш js код на гитхабе - я не знаю как Вы вообще можете рассуждать о том, идеальный ли js или нет :-)

Comment: @overthesanity мне кажется вы немного не объективны, у меня на гитХаб есть только один репозиторий по `JS`, уточните пожалуйста, что в коде моей `ES6` Ориентированной репе не так? Я внимательно выслушаю. Мне будет интересно ваше мнение которое перечит мнению Лидов которые рассматривали эту репу. :)

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов, никому неинтересно мнение Ваших лидов, первое, что заметит любой js'ер - это стиль написания кода, который Вы используйте, мне что-то подсказывает, что это похоже на стандарт PSR) К тому же сам создатель PHP Р. Лердорф сказал, что язык - это просто инструмент решения проблемы, поэтому, следуя из того, что Вы написали пару строчек кода на jquery + es6, и это было оценено Вашими лидами, как новшество - не стоит делать выводы, что js это плохой язык

Comment: @overthesanity молодой человек, вы откровенно Немете какой-то не связный бренд без представления фактов. Я вас попрошу написать мне подробнее в ВК что именно не так с моим кодом, или промолчать. Ваша компетенция в `JS` Вызывает сомнения.

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов, я Вам уже объяснил свою позицию, то, что Вы сразу переходите на личности - уже ставит под сомнения кол-во Ваших аргументов. Я бы начать спорить насчет лидов оценивавших Ваш код (которых Вы скорее всего выдумали)...но какой в этом смысл, к тому же это противоречит правилам форума, учитывая тот факт, что Вы САМИ подняли эту тему. Удачи Вам, Cheers :-)

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов, код вида _`(key in this.data) ? true : false`_ наводит на мысли :-)

Comment: @Grundy на какие мысли, извините?

Comment: Мне все же интересно `pk.One = `${pk.One}, 111-395`` реально лучше чем `pk.One += ', 111-395'` ?

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько, да.

Comment: Как по мне, если в js оператор + это конкатенация то почему бы не использовать короткий вариант +=(может вместо + юзать concat?), товарищи если не нубы то поймут, даже если во всех языках мира по другому делают, зачем на них смотреть? js это отдельный язык с большими особенностями, тут надо использовать что быстрее и понятнее для программистов на этом языке. Насколько вижу += короче и читал что быстрее, поэтому я думаю что это отличный вариант для той ситуации.

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько, зачем вообще тогда использовать возможности `es2015`? Давайте откажемся от стрелочных функций, классов и шаблонных литералов :-)

Answer (score -4):

Более инкапсулированным решением будет создать метод для строки:

```js
String.prototype.function_name=function(add,separator=', '){
  return this.split(separator).concat(add).join(separator)
}
var pk = {
  One : '811-111'
}
pk.One=pk.One.function_name('111-395')
console.log(pk.One)
```

Этот метод также предотвратит проблему лишнего разделителя при добавлении данных в пустую строку.

Comment: Модификация прототипа? Это же ужасно. Такого нельзя делать.

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов уважаемый, js - это прототипно-ориентированный язык. Ужасно наоборот ничего не делать с такими громадными возможностями JSа.

Comment: Модификация стандартного прототипа, это никак не хорошо. Тем более не в `camelCase` Формате. Вы можете подробнее узнать об этом сами.

Comment: https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch Вот например.

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов аргумент "никак не хорошо" и придирание к тому как я называю методы. Если хотите что-то доказать, то потрудитесь сами объясняться.